# For loop does not display all entries in section

Tags: forloop, limit

I have a for loop for all entries.  There is no limit set, yet the loop is not displaying all the entries.  The missing entries are the oldest.  These missing entries do appear on category specific pages.

There are no errors.  I have approximately 100 entries.  The for loop is only displaying the most recent 80 or so.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

```
{% for post in craft.entries.section('posts') %}
                {% if loop.first and craft.request.pageNum == 1 %}  
                    <div class="box col-sm-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="thumb featured dark-overlay">
                        <div class="photo">
                            <a href="{{post.url}}">
                                <img src="{{post.postImage.first().getUrl('featuredImage')}}" alt="" width="715" height="715">

                                <span class="info"><strong class="big-title">{{post.title}}</strong><span class="excerpt">{{post.tagline}}</span>
                                <em class="arrow-right"></em></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div class="box col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <div class="photo">
                            <a href="{{post.url}}">
                                <img src="{{post.postImage.first().getUrl('thumbImage')}}" alt="" width="434" height="434">
                                <span class="info"><strong class="title">{{post.title}}</strong>
                                    <!--<span class="excerpt">{{post.tagline}}</span>-->
                                <em class="arrow-right"></em></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft has a default limit of a 100 elements returned via an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel). To pull *all* elements, you'll need to explicitly set `limit` to `null`:

```
{% for post in craft.entries.section('posts').limit(null) %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```